# How do i inherit the data members from parent to base class

Tags: python, mysql-python

I am inheriting data members from my parent class to the base class by calling its `__init__` method , but keep on getting the following error message

> database_creator.__init__(self , username , password , m_database)
>   NameError: name 'username' is not defined

IF I remember correctly the above line is used to inherit members from another class.I am using MySQL.connector to connect to the database and perform queries using class declaration .The following is the part of  the code

```
class database_creator: # the class that connects to the database
    def __init__(self , username , password , m_database):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password 
        self.cursor  =None  # this is the cursor 
        self.connect = None  # this is the cnx the mysql object 
        self.tables = ['server','personal_info','credentials']   # this shows how many databse table are there
        self.m_database = m_database

class insert_database_values(database_creator):
    def __init__(self):
        database_creator.__init__(self , username , password , m_database)
```

Comment: The `__init__` of the `insert_database_values` must take `username`, `password`, and `m_database` as parameters before passing them to the constructor of `database_creator`.

Comment: So , i have to pass the actual values of those parameters ?

Comment: Surely. How else would Python know about them?

Comment: Either you pass actual values while calling database_creator.__init__() method or you can pass args to __init__() method of insert_database_values class

Answer (score 0):

In short, it's already appeared in the comments. You are correct:

```
class insert_database_values(database_creator):
```

means your new class `insert_database_values` inherits from class `database_creator`. However, you also overrode its constructor (`__init__`) with a new one which takes no parameters (except for instance of `self`), hence when you run:

```
def __init__(self):
    database_creator.__init__(self , username , password , m_database)
```

Variables `username`, ... are indeed unknown to the interpreter in this scope.

In fact, in this case unless you're planning to add more functionality you have omitted to the `insert_database_values` constructor, there is no need to define your own only to call the parent one, just skip those two lines and rely on the inheritance to work for you. Otherwise, you could:

```
def __init__(self, username , password , m_database):
    database_creator.__init__(self , username , password , m_database)
```

And add your other instance initialization steps as needed.